# Set nameserver in WHM with VPS that has no domain name?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cpanel, vps, nameserver

I have a new VPS I want to use to manage sites on. I need to set up nameservers so that I can point the domain names to the new servers. I know nameservers usually look like `ns1.example.com` where `example.com` is the domain name of the VPS, but my VPS does not have a domain name, I just access it via the servers IP.

Is it OK to use a domain name of one of the sites I am trying to set up instead?

Answer (score 1):

Nameservers can have DNS records for other domains too. For example:

`ns1.abccompany.com` and `ns2.abccompany.com` provides DNS for:

- abccompany.com
- abccompany.net
- xyzcompany.com

The nameservers (`ns1.abccompany.com` and `ns2.abccompany.com`) need to be setup in your DNS settings for `abccompany.com`, and then set the same nameservers in your other domains, along with the "A" record indicating which IP address these would be served from.

So yes, you can use one domain to act as the nameservers for the others.